# Checking Background Resource Android

Tags: android, background

My XML file contain four buttons, lets say Button A, B, C and Confirm. In my main file, when Button A is clicked, Button B will get the image background of Button A. That posts no problems. However, my problem is that I wanted that when Confirm is clicked, Button C will have another background image depending on Button B's background image. How do I do that? To simplify, I do not know how to check the image background of Button B (which depends on Button A) and it will determine the image of Button C.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy the background from buttonB to buttonC:

```
buttonC.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonB.getBackground());
```

To see what background you have you can use the Views tag. Let's use some strings to identify the backgrounds:

We set some background on buttonA that we call "BACK1",then also call `buttonA.setTag("BACK1");`

When you later copy the background from A->B, also do `buttonB.setTag(buttonA.getTag());`

Now whenever you need to know what background buttonB have, just check the tag with smth like:

```
if ( "BACK1".equals(buttonB.getTag()) ) { /* We have BACK1 */ }
```

Of course you can use smth better in the tag, an resource ID so you can use a switch statement.

Comment: yes i know that, what i wanted is the checker.. how can i compare the image background of a button to another button image or to another R.drawable.something?

Comment: great answer! i tried it and it worked well! :) thanks for that especially for giving the exact codes and detailed!